# Linear first order ODE doubt

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have two linear ODE  :

*Equation1* :

> $(e^y)y′+(e^y)y+(e^y)x = 0$
>
> $L1[y] = e^y\cdot x$

*Equation2* :

> $(e^y)y′+(e^y)y = 0$
>
> $L2[y] = 0$

*Equation1* is inhomogeneous while *Equation2* is homogeneous.

What are the associated differential operators in the Left-Hand-Side of both equation ?

Are the differential operators $L1 = L2 = (e^y(d/dx) + 1)$   ?

And the ultimate question :

We know every first order linear ODE can be written as $a(x)y' + b(x)y + c(x) = 0$.
On the other hand, every first order linear ODE must be that the linear combination of the solutions is also a solution ( is that right ? ).

*Equation2* holds the last property i mentioned while *Equation1* doesn't hold.
Another thing is that both *Equation1* and *Equation2* are not written in $a(x)y' + b(x)y +c(x)=0$ form.

So my doubt is :
Which one of these 2 equations ( *Equation1* and *Equation2* ) can be considered linear ( holds homogenity and additivity property  ) ?

Comment: You should consider editing it using TeX to make it more readable.  Perhaps quickly reading the FAQ to see how to TeXify your questions will help.  I would edit it but I'm not exactly sure what you're asking so I might end up destroying the question

Comment: Hello again, muzzlator.Thanks for the tip

Comment: Why dont' you simplify ? $$(e^y)y′+(e^y)y+(e^y)x = 0$$ $$y′+y+x = 0$$